# What should I do about otherwise good edits that include nonsense in the edit summary?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have recently come across a certain user, not going to post here to avoid meta affect, that is posting noise in the suggested edit summary. For example:

[image: Noisy comment]

Apart from their comment, the edits seem to be good, is there anything I can do to contact this user about changing their behaviour? Or even a moderator to message them about this?

Comment: I guess you could flag it if said user makes a habit out of it. If not, what's the harm?

Comment: @Cerbrus I've seen 2 or 3 of them in the past few reviews so I'd say it is a habit

Comment: I don't see how that's any worse than the default "Added x characters in body" type comments. They're both equally useless.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Those aren't "default" for anyone except 2k users, and while a lack of edit summary is annoying for 2kers, it's really bad for suggested edits, since it makes it harder to determine whether it should be accepted or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While I frequently encourage editors who still need their edits reviewed to leave clear comments, my encouragement is to help the reviewers understand why the edits were made to help prevent rejections due to confusion.  But if the editor doesn't care, I don't see a real reason to make a big deal about it.

That being said, pinging the user on one of their approved edits (using the @user notation) would be a way to address this concern directly with him.  One possible point you could make directly to the user is to remind them that the edit summaries help explain why the end was made for historical context.

Comment: The Edit Summary also serves as a little explanation to the OP - what was changed and why. That's why 2K+ users still get to write Edit Summaries.

Comment: Edit summaries are for more than just reviewers. They're also useful for anyone viewing the edit history of a post. Mentally I've always kinda seen it as Edit Summary = Commit Message.

Comment: You could also _Improve edit_ first to show what a edit summary should look like.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I wouldn't disagree with that, except that it isn't required for 2K users when they edit.  If they felt it was as important as a commit message, it would be required for everyone

Comment: @SQB it is extremely unlikely that would be an effective strategy.  Few users will review the following "improved" edit to see what they missed, especially if you improved the edit, rather than rejecting it.  And I don't think you can change an edit summary without actually changing something else in the post.  If there is nothing left to edit, you wouldn't be able to change the summary

Comment: @psubsee2003 what I meant was for to change the edit summary first, and _then_ to \@ping the user to tell him what was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Once the edit is approved, you can [@ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232) the editor asking to stop this behaviour. If the edit itself is good, even without clarification, I don't see any reason to reject it. After all, it's not really visible; the only places you can see the edit summary are the revision history and the timeline. IMHO, an *offensive* edit summary would be reason for a custom moderator flag. With these kind of edit summaries, the editor only risks his/her edits being rejected, but doesn't do real harm to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably first try the method of contacting the user that has been mentioned by others (i.e.  [@ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/271271) the person on a question where an edit of theirs was approved). Users who are conscientious enough to be editing posts with good changes will often respond positively (or at least change their behavior) when something they are doing wrong is politely explained to them. If they did not change, I might start Rejecting and Editing.

A somewhat more drastic solution would be to Reject & Edit. You could then do exactly the same edits, but with a clear edit summary.

Arguably, Reject & Edit is actually the correct thing to do. The period of time where users don't have enough reputation to edit posts without having those edits reviewed is intended to provide those users with time to learn the correct way to edit a post. Edit summaries explain the changes for reviewers, for the OP, and in the edit history. Having garbage in the edit summary is detrimental for all uses. Thus, intentionally providing garbage for the edit summary is clearly not the correct thing to do when editing a post.

Comment: While i agree that an edit summary is good to have, the argument that it is important enough go warrant rejecting an otherwise good edit doesn't make sense to me because 2K users do not have to provide summaries. If they were that important, it would be a required fields for everyone

Comment: @psubsee2003, Reject & Edit certainly isn't my first choice. The counter to your argument that edit summaries are not required for >2k users is that they *are* required for <2k users. If they were not sufficiently important to be part of judging the totality of an edit, then they would be just suggested, not required, for <2k users. By intentionally entering garbage, the person is explicitly trying to get around a requirement that an edit summary be provided while doing so in a way that shows contempt for that requirement.

Comment: Entering nonsense is not a lot worse than the very common "improved formatting", "grammar", or (my personal favorite) "grammer".  If the edit is good enough to be understood without the comment, then it should be accepted.  If it isn't and whatever comment that is there isn't enough to explain the situation, then it should be rejected.

Comment: @psubsee2003, (I like your favorite.) If an edit summary, which at least marginally describes the edit, is not important, then it would not be *required* for <2K users. What you are advocating is a feature request to make the edit summary not required for <2k users. I will say that some edits do reasonably require edit summaries to not be rejected. One such situation would be moving information provided by the OP (in a comment, or mistakenly as an answer) into the question. Depending on how that is done, it can be non-obvious that the info came from the OP, not the editor.